# How do I get new video release into my website

Tags: php, javascript, feed

I am wondering on how do I get to show movies, tv series, anime etc. that came out on DVD's to my site l;ike http://www.blockbuster.com/ does. Can i just feed it off IMDB or any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you could consume and display their RSS feed:

http://www.blockbuster.com/rss/newRelease

Comment: Thanks and I am guessing that by installing an RSS reader would help it to show the images as well?

Comment: @kwek-kwek: The RSS feed items for new releases on Blockbuster seem to link to at least thumbnails of the movie posters, so you can probably parse those out and reference them.

Comment: @kwek-kwek: Note also that there may be similar feeds on IMDB, Amazon, etc.  They might have more and/or better information or images.  I just haven't checked those ones.

Comment: @david: I don't quite get the parsing out and referencing them part, forgive me for my slowness just been on this subject for about 3 hours now... this is as close as I got to.. heheh

Comment: @kwek-kwek: As I understand it from the original question, you're looking to present on a website a custom list of new DVD releases, correct?  Your web site could either just point users to the existing RSS feed or, to present the content in your own way, your server-side code would access the RSS feed itself and parse/transform it into custom content to serve on your site.